# How to check some elements of a matrix and generate a set of matrices accordingly?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I'm trying to check elements of a 2D array (matrix) and generate a number of matrices (of equal size) depending on some conditions as below:

Consider my matrix:

```
x = [[1, 0, 2],[7, 0, 7],[1, 1, 1]]
```

I need to check for the (2) and generate two matrices where the position of (2) will be replaced by 0 and 1 respectively. I also need to check for the 7's and generate 3 combinations of the matrix with values of 7 being (0,1),(1,0),(1,1) respectively. This mean the total number of matrices generated are 6 as follows:

```
[[1, 0, 0],[0, 0, 1],[1, 1, 1]]
[[1, 0, 0],[1, 0, 0],[1, 1, 1]]
[[1, 0, 0],[1, 0, 1],[1, 1, 1]]
[[1, 0, 1],[0, 0, 1],[1, 1, 1]]
[[1, 0, 1],[1, 0, 0],[1, 1, 1]]
[[1, 0, 1],[1, 0, 1],[1, 1, 1]]
```

There can be more than 1 (2), and the position of 7's can be vertical or hirizental.

I've tried a naiive way just looping through x looking for 2's and appending:

```
for i in range(len(x)):
  for j in range(len(x[0])):
    if x[i][j] == 2:
      inter[i][j] = 0
      test.append(inter)
      inter2[i][j] = 1
      test.append(inter2)
```

But that only works if I have the value of 2 only. I've also tried converting to numpy array and using where() to find the indexes of 2's and 7's, but then don't know how that can be used to generate the required outcome. Any thoughts?

Comment: when there is more than two (2)s, do you want all of them replaced with all 0 (and all 1) or any combinations of 0 and 1?

Comment: Alternating, meaning if I have [[1, 0, 0],[2, 0, 2],[1, 1, 1]], my result should be: [[1, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0],[1, 1, 1]],[[1, 0, 0],[0, 0, 1],[1, 1, 1]],[[1, 0, 0],[1, 0, 0],[1, 1, 1]],[[1, 0, 0],[1, 0, 1],[1, 1, 1]]

Comment: There is no results after ':' in your comment? I think you might have missed it. Please see if the posted answer is what you are looking for. If not, please elaborate. Thank you

Comment: [[1, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0],[1, 1, 1]],[[1, 0, 0],[0, 0, 1],[1, 1, 1]],[[1, 0, 0],[1, 0, 0],[1, 1, 1]],[[1, 0, 0],[1, 0, 1],[1, 1, 1]]

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear, 1's and 0's in the original matrix remain the same, 2's to be changed with 0/1, if I have one (2), then I get (0,1) in that position, if I have three (2's), I get (000,001,010,011,100,101,110,111) regardless where the 2 is located.

Answer (score 0):

The conditions described are very vague. If I understand correctly, you want this:

```
sevens = [[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]
twos = [0,1]

for i in twos:
    for j in sevens:
        m = x.copy()
        m[m==2] = i
        m[m==7] = j
        print(m)
```

output:

```
[[1 0 0]
 [0 0 1]
 [1 1 1]]
[[1 0 0]
 [1 0 0]
 [1 1 1]]
[[1 0 0]
 [1 0 1]
 [1 1 1]]
[[1 0 1]
 [0 0 1]
 [1 1 1]]
[[1 0 1]
 [1 0 0]
 [1 1 1]]
[[1 0 1]
 [1 0 1]
 [1 1 1]]
```

---

**UPDATE**: per OP's comment for (2)s multiplicities:

```
x = np.array([[2, 0, 2],[7, 0, 7],[1, 1, 1]])
sevens = [[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]
v = (x==2).sum()*([0,1],)
twos = np.array(np.meshgrid(*v)).T.reshape(-1,2)

for i in twos:
    for j in sevens:
        m = x.copy()
        m[m==2] = i
        m[m==7] = j
        print(m)
```

output:

```
[[0 0 0]
 [0 0 1]
 [1 1 1]]
[[0 0 0]
 [1 0 0]
 [1 1 1]]
[[0 0 0]
 [1 0 1]
 [1 1 1]]
[[0 0 1]
 [0 0 1]
 [1 1 1]]
[[0 0 1]
 [1 0 0]
 [1 1 1]]
[[0 0 1]
 [1 0 1]
 [1 1 1]]
[[1 0 0]
 [0 0 1]
 [1 1 1]]
[[1 0 0]
 [1 0 0]
 [1 1 1]]
[[1 0 0]
 [1 0 1]
 [1 1 1]]
[[1 0 1]
 [0 0 1]
 [1 1 1]]
[[1 0 1]
 [1 0 0]
 [1 1 1]]
[[1 0 1]
 [1 0 1]
 [1 1 1]]
```

Comment: I get a different answer: [[0, 1], [7, 0, 7], [1, 1, 1]]
[[1, 0], [7, 0, 7], [1, 1, 1]]
[[1, 1], [7, 0, 7], [1, 1, 1]]
[[0, 1], [7, 0, 7], [1, 1, 1]]
[[1, 0], [7, 0, 7], [1, 1, 1]]
[[1, 1], [7, 0, 7], [1, 1, 1]]

Comment: @user12195720 Do you mean the output of this code is not the same as what is printed? How can one even get a non-rectangular array as output? I suspect you might have not run the code as above.